# How to setup H2 database for persisting data with unbalanced data distribution?

Tags: h2

Regarding the [SuperNode problem](https://www.datastax.com/blog/solution-supernode-problem) like in social network data, when some entity is huge (Barack Obama) then having OneToMany relationship and Secondary Index for doing JOINS can perform quite poorly whenever you hit the "HotKey".

Are there any recommendations how to tackle this problem in H2? Secondary Index in H2 works by creating new `MVMap` for each new chunk of data, so basically there are no limits, it will just get too long response time I suppose.

H2 does not support Index with constraint, like :

```
CREATE INDEX name_index ON TEST(NAME) WHERE NOT NAME = 'hotKey';
```

So that one could store

There are options like `CREATE MEMORY TABLE` for instance to have indexes kept in-memory, but I don't even know when this option comes handy.